# D3DXCreateTextureFromFile just returns a pointer rather than any decent message for me?

Tags: textures, assert, directx-9

The following code for C++ DirectX Visual Studio 2012:

```
    HRESULT result;

    sprite = NULL;
    result = D3DXCreateSprite( gfx.d3dDevice, &sprite );
    assert( !FAILED( result ) );

    gTexture = NULL;
    result = D3DXCreateTextureFromFile( gfx.d3dDevice, _fileName, &gTexture );
    assert( !FAILED( result ) );
```

says that the first assert the result is S_OK, but when it gets to the second assert, it just states a pointer and gives an assertion fail error window? I can't tell what's wrong with it because it is giving me nothing to work with!

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

_filename is a .jpg -> "Images/Scene/Area/Background.jpg"

EDIT:: I have found the problem but still, how do I get back a result that would help me solve this issue better? It was a bad file path... I don't understand why result doesn't give me anything back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `DXGetErrorString` and `DXGetErrorDescription` functions to get info about the errors.

Also, you shouldn't use assertions for this. These are errors that can happen under normal circumstances, not development errors.